# Resize textarea on input

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I wanted to create a auto-growing textarea, so I used [this](http://usefulangle.com/post/41/javascript-textarea-autogrow-adjust-height-based-on-content) guide. It works well, but there is a small problem. When you insert large texts and delete them, the textarea has a bigger size than it should have.
With every inserted character, the size is reduced by 1-2 px, so with a few inserted characters the height is right again.

To recreate the worng scrollHeight, insert 'a *\n* b *\n* c *\n* d *\n* e' into the textarea.Now delete all of it. The textarea keeps a bigger size than it needs now. With every inserted character the textarea will adjust its size to the right value.

```js
$("#message-box").on('input', function() {
  var scroll_height = $("#message-box").get(0).scrollHeight;
  $("#message-box").css('height', scroll_height + 'px');

  $("body > p").remove();
  $("body").append("<p>ScrollHeight: " + scroll_height + "</p>");
});
```

```css
#message-box {
  resize: none;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="message-box"></textarea>
```

**[Here is the example in CodePen](https://codepen.io/gehtnet/pen/dybjQWd)**

How can I get the textarea to resize to the smallest possible value immediately after a big text is deleted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reset it quickly to `auto` before going for `scrollHeight` and reassagning it:

```js
const resizeOnType = (evt) => {
  const elTextarea = evt.currentTarget;
  elTextarea.style.height = "auto";
  elTextarea.style.height = `${elTextarea.scrollHeight}px`;
};

document.querySelectorAll(".resizeOnType").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("input", resizeOnType);
});
```

```css
#message-box {
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  /* min-height: 100px; /* IF NEEDED, ADD SOME DESIRED MIN-HEIGHT */
}
```

```html
<textarea class="resizeOnType" id="message-box"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this will help you to get the desire output. I have update the height on `resize`.

```js
messagebox();

function messagebox() {
  var text = $('.message-box');

  text.each(function() {
    $(this).attr('rows', 1);
    resize($(this));
  });

  text.on('input', function() {
    resize($(this));
  });

  function resize($text) {
    $text.css('height', 'auto');
    $text.css('height', $text[0].scrollHeight + 'px');
  }
}
```

```css
.message-box {
  resize: none;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="message-box"></textarea>
```