# Jquery textarea auto grow and reduce

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to create a `textarea` which is preloaded with content. Its height should be `auto` when content is there but when it's empty the height should become `4.2rem`. When I enter text in it should increase and decrease the height to a maximum height of `7.7rem` using jQuery.

How can I do this?

```css
.textAreaGrow {
  padding: 1.8rem 0 .8rem;
  height: 4.2rem;
  max-height: 7.7rem;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="textAreaGrow">Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs.</textarea>
```

Comment: Auto? As in `height:auto` or assuming the height of the content?

Comment: Hi Spectric, thanks for reply, i want preloaded content height but maximum height should be 7.7rem(77px)

Comment: Not sure if this would help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772260/textarea-auto-height

Comment: What stopped you from doing a small research i.e: [Resize textarea on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57953324/resize-textarea-on-input) and applying some Math.max()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to set the height of the textarea to the scrollHeight of the element when it has a height of around 0px everytime the user inputs into the textarea.

We can add another `if` statement to check whether the textarea is empty. If it is, set the height to its initial height.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let txtArea = $('.textAreaGrow');
  txtArea.on('input', updateHeight);

  function updateHeight() {
    let t = txtArea;
    if (t.val().trim() == "") {
      t.css('height', '4.2em');
    } else {
      t.css('height', '0.1px');
      t.css('height', t[0].scrollHeight);
    }
  }
  updateHeight();
})
```

```css
.textAreaGrow {
  height: 4.2rem;
  max-height: 7.7rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textAreaGrow">Preloaded text

With newlines too??</textarea>
```

Comment: thanks spectric for the solution, the codes is working fine but it's not taking the height of preloaded text.

Comment: @ajay I've added support for preloaded text.

Comment: @ajay Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to use another element than `textarea`. And then give the element the attribute `contenteditable`. Then it is easier to control the styles. But then you lack the functionallity of a form element like `textarea`. So, it depends on what the element should be used for.

```css
.textAreaGrow {
  border: thin gray solid;
  padding: 1.8rem 0 .8rem;
  width: 20em;
  min-height: 4.2rem;
  max-height: 7.7rem;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="textAreaGrow" contenteditable>
  Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs.
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't assume the height of its content though

Comment: By using your suggestion... If I select a text portion and hit CTRL+B  ...could you tell with what evil are we now working with?